# How to login using robobrowser with CSRF token?

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

I am currently trying to login into

https://customersso1.fortinet.com/saml-idp/login/?next=

and after login head to https://support.fortinet.com/Information/ProductLifeCycle.aspx

and **scrape** all the tables in it.

I tried various ways and settled on robobrowser to be the ideal choice to do it. However the website has CSRF Middleware token in it and does not allow me to login.

Also the get_form() function in Robobrowser does not fetch the username and password field for me to login. (There is only 1 form in the login page) I have provided the credentials as its public information and anyone can create an ID to access that information

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = RoboBrowser()
br.open('https://customersso1.fortinet.com/saml-idp/login/?next=')

form = br.get_form()
form["id_username"] = "csmcoe.global@global.ntt"
form["id_password"] = 'Csmcoe@123'
#form["csrffieldname"] = 'X2fOGlgm0lBH60k2SqPiJ5BkFv7lRzKo' 
br.submit_form(form)
```

when you parse the form

```
form.parsed
```

you get (when you inspect the webpage you will notice div container in the form but not when you scrape it. As there is no username element I am not able to login via form)

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off" id="login_form" method="post">
<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" type="hidden" value="tzDXaug8hGlNO7h6oDDU3tel80mdA9AZ"/>
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/"/>
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
</form>
```

Also any other way other than robobrowser is also appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

# Get csrfmiddlewaretoken
url = "https://customersso1.fortinet.com/saml-idp/login/?next="
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
csrfmiddlewaretoken = doc.select(
    'form#login_form>input@name=csrfmiddlewaretoken>value()')
    
username = 'your user name'
password = 'your password'
# login
html = req.post(url,
         'csrfmiddlewaretoken=' + csrfmiddlewaretoken + '&next=&username' +
         username + '&password=' + password,
         header={'Referer': url})
print (html) # See what the problem is

# Get next page
html = req.get(
    'https://support.fortinet.com/Information/ProductLifeCycle.aspx')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print(doc.title.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, Appreciate it @dabingsou for your answer. When you print the doc.title.text you will get Fortinet SSO meaning the login was not successfull. When you inspect the document csrf token from chrome you get X2fOGlgm0lBH60k2SqPiJ5BkFv7lRzKo (different than the one used in the code here)

Comment: @Tango_charlie I don't have an account, so I don't have a test. You see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Tango_charlie Login to the page with your account to see what parameters are included in the request.

Comment: Thanks @dabingsou the login URL is the main problem as I am notable to decipher the login URL to put the req.post (the credentials are in question if interested in testing)